# Sort Cells Into Multiple Lists By First Letter

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to write a VBA script to sort a cell into a group of ranges split by the first letter. Namely I want to write a glossary/dictionary type thing and I want to be able to write a word, and have it automatically sort into the set of lists.

I have a few problems with this, primarily because I have no experience writing VBA scripts and little other programming knowledge. Some problems I came here to solve:

How do I assign these ranges more efficiently (notice they are all 3 columns apart)
How do I select the cell I want to sort into my array

This is what I was able to do with what I found:

```
Sub Sort()
'
' Sortme Macro
'
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ColA = Range(a6, a1048576)
ColB = Range(e6, e1048576)
ColC = Range(h6, h1048576)
ColD = Range(k6, k1048576)
ColE = Range(n6, n1048576)
ColF = Range(q6, q1048576)
ColG = Range(t6, t1048576)
ColH = Range(w6, w1048576)
ColI = Range(z6, z1048576)
ColJ = Range(ac6, ac1048576)
ColK = Range(af6, af1048576)
ColL = Range(ai6, ai1048576)
ColM = Range(al6, al1048576)
ColN = Range(ao6, ao1048576)
ColO = Range(ar6, ar1048576)
ColP = Range(au6, au1048576)
ColQ = Range(ax6, ax1048576)
ColR = Range(ba6, bb1048576)
ColS = Range(bd6, bd1048576)
ColT = Range(bg6, bg1048576)
ColU = Range(bj6, bj1048576)
ColV = Range(bm6, bm1048576)
ColW = Range(bp6, bp1048576)
ColX = Range(bs6, bs1048576)
ColY = Range(bv6, bv1048576)
ColZ = Range(by6, by1048576)
On Error Resume Next
```

Right here I want to know how to select a cell, also for loops ? :

```
For left(range(Thiscell))

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColA")) Is Nothing Then
    Range(ColA).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
End For
```

Is this how I end a for loop in this language?

```
End Sub
'
End Sub
```

This is what i have:

![my excel sheet before any vba works and I have to type everything in by hand]:[[http://imgur.com/K5diRM9]](https://imgur.com/K5diRM9])

Sorry if this doesn't really make sense but thanks in advance anyway :)

Comment: Why is it a worksheet change event? Does `Range(a6, a1048576)` actually work? (Usually the convention is `Range("A6:A1048576")`. What are you trying to do with your macro? In VBA `End Sub` is the end of the subroutine. With `for` loops, you'd want to do something like `For i = 1 to 10` then `next i` which will loop to the next `i`.

Comment: Just to clarify.  You want words that are typed into a given cell to be placed in the column that corresponds with its first letter and then sort that column in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

Type a word into A1 of your sheet named "Dictionary".  Then run this macro.  It will put the word into the correct alphabetized column and then sort that column if needed.  The words begin on row 6, which is where I think you want them to start.  you can adjust it to accept the word f4rom an input box or add a list of words from another worksheet column.

```
Sub putWordInAlphebeticalColumn()

Dim columnArr, wordToAlphebetize As String, lastUsedRw As Long
Dim i As Integer, isAlpha As Boolean, firstLetter As String
Dim colNumber As Integer

columnArr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", _
                        "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", _
                        "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", _
                        "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")


wordToAlphebetize = Sheets("Dictionary").Range("A1").Value

If Len(wordToAlphebetize) > 0 Then ' Determine if string is all alpha characters
    For i = 1 To Len(Trim(wordToAlphebetize))
            Select Case Asc(Mid(wordToAlphebetize, i, 1))
                Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                    isAlpha = True
                Case Else
                    If i > 1 And Mid(Trim(wordToAlphebetize), i, 1) = "-" Then
                        isAlpha = True
                    Else
                        isAlpha = False
                        MsgBox "Word contains non-alpha character(s)"
                        Sheets("Dictionary").Range("A1").Value = ""
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
            End Select
    Next i
End If


firstLetter = Mid(wordToAlphebetize, 1, 1)

For i = 0 To 26
    If UCase(firstLetter) = columnArr(i) Then
        colNumber = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i


lastUsedRw = Sheets("Dictionary").Range(columnArr(colNumber) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Dictionary").Range(columnArr(colNumber) & "6:" & columnArr(colNumber) & lastUsedRw + 6)
    Set c = .Find(LCase(wordToAlphebetize), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Word already exists"
        Sheets("Dictionary").Range("A1").Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Sheets("Dictionary").Range(columnArr(colNumber) & "6").Value = "" Then
            Sheets("Dictionary").Range(columnArr(colNumber) & "6").Value = wordToAlphebetize
        Else
            Sheets("Dictionary").Range(columnArr(colNumber) & lastUsedRw + 1).Value = wordToAlphebetize
        End If
        lastUsedRw = Sheets("Dictionary").Range(columnArr(colNumber) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastUsedRw > 6 Then
            Range(columnArr(colNumber) & "6:" & columnArr(colNumber) & lastUsedRw).Select
            Worksheets("Dictionary").Sort.SortFields.Clear
            Worksheets("Dictionary").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(columnArr(colNumber) & "6") _
                , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With Worksheets("Dictionary").Sort
                .SetRange Range(columnArr(colNumber) & "6:" & columnArr(colNumber) & lastUsedRw)
                .Header = xlGuess
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End If

    End If
End With


End Sub
```